# Error in using text to speech engine(NSSpeechSynthesizer on Mac OS) pyttsx3

Tags: python, text-to-speech, apple-m1, pyttsx3

I am doing a tutorial on voice-based assistant. But I keep getting error while compiling the code. I am using M1 mac.
my code:

```
   import pyttsx3
  
   engine = pyttsx3.init('nsss')  
   engine.say('Hello sir, how may I help you, sir.')   
   engine.runAndWait()
```

code error:

[image]

I also installed pyobjc module as some other answers suggested on StackOverflow. Still not working.

Stacktrace with Python 3.9.7:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PyObjCTools import AppHelper
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyObjCTools/AppHelper.py", line 32, in <module>
    from Foundation import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'NSAutoreleasePool' from 'Foundation' (unknown location)
```

Comment: Please add the stack trace as text, not an image.

Comment: I get the same error on a M1 chip. But it works on an older Mac. Fell free to open an issue on the project website: https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues